# Too many PhantomJS processes

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I'm using the Selenium PhantomJS webdriver in a celery queue with two concurrent workers.

While I only have two concurrent workers, I often get about 50 PhantomJS processes in the activity monitor, with a huge memory footprint. These processes don't seem to close properly, even when I call the `driver.quit()` method.

My code looks as follows:

```
class Scrape:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1280, 800)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.driver.quit()
```

I'm using this with the `with` statement to ensure proper cleanup. Yet it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: did you see this: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/162, namely last 2 comments: "this issue will happen if phantomjs is installed with npm", so they suggest to install it using something else (apt-get / homebrew)

Comment: @KirilS. You might want to write that as an answer, since that indeed got rid of the problem! Thanks!

Comment: sure, did. Glad it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this issue](http://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/162), namely last 2 comments,

> this issue will happen if phantomjs is installed with npm

So they suggest to install it using something else (apt-get / homebrew).